# Active Tabbed Radio is selected?

Tags: java, swing, state, jtabbedpane, jradiobutton

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TabbedPaneExample {
JFrame f;
TabbedPaneExample(){
f=new JFrame();

    JButton check = new JButton("Check state of RadioButton");
    check.setBounds(50,280,200,60);
    //selected tabbed radio button is selected ?

    JPanel p1=new JPanel();
    JPanel p2=new JPanel();
    JPanel p3=new JPanel();
    JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("Radio");
    JRadioButton rb2= new JRadioButton("Radio");
    JRadioButton rb3 = new JRadioButton("Radio");
    rb1.setBounds(150,170,80,100);
    rb2.setBounds(150,170,80,100);
    rb3.setBounds(150,170,80,100);
    p1.add(rb1);
    p2.add(rb2);
    p3.add(rb3);
    JTabbedPane tp=new JTabbedPane();
    tp.setBounds(50,50,200,200);
    tp.add("main",p1);
    tp.add("visit",p2);
    tp.add("help",p3);

    check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            // Q: is the radio button of the selected tab is checked
            // what is the logic i can put here to get result
            // show result into JOptionPane
        }
    });


    f.add(tp);
    f.add(check);
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TabbedPaneExample();

}}
```

Q: show radio button state(selected or unselected) of the active tab:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pjIM.jpg]

I have three tab and these tab have the radio button, I want to get state(selected or unselected) of the radio button with respect to any active tab!

Comment: Read the `JTabbedPane` API, especially all the "getter" methods. There are methods to return the selected tab index and another method to get the component of the selected tab index. Once you have the selected component you check the state of the radio button using methods of the JRadioButtron. This is basic programming. Follow the methods of the API.

Comment: `f.setLayout(null);` Use. *Layouts!* If not now, then certainly before you come asking us why the layout breaks. **Edit:** Also, please read the helpful tag pop-ups before slapping them on a post, and also look at the other tags suggested as possible alternates - for a more specific one.